# Reading Data from Serial Port and Plotting in Real Time

Tags: matlab, arduino

I am looking to take in data from a temperature sensor on an Arduino Uno board and have matlab store the data while also plotting the data on a graph in real time to monitor sensor changes. This will eventually be implemented with a different sensor and this more of a proof of concept. I have two issues currently troubling me:

1) I need to be gathering the data points 1000x a second (which my current code cannot do)

2) After several seconds of monitoring the data a great deal of noise enters the system

**Here is my matlab code**

```
SerialPort = 'com6';

s = serial(SerialPort, 'BaudRate', 250000, 'DataBits', 8);

fopen(s);

voltage = 0;

t = 0;

y = 1;

voltage = fscanf(s);
VoltageValue(y,1)=str2double(voltage);
h = animatedline(t,VoltageValue(y,1));

xlim([0 1000]);
ylim([100 200]);


tic
while t <= 1000
voltage = fscanf(s);
VoltageValue(y,1)=str2double(voltage);
addpoints(h, t, VoltageValue(y,1));
 t= t+1;
 y= y+1;
 drawnow
end
toc

fclose(s);
delete(s);
clear s;
```

**Here is my arduino code**

```
int tmppin = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

Serial.begin(250000);
pinMode(tmppin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

int tempreading = analogRead(tmppin);

Serial.println(tempreading);
}
```

Comment: you won't get 1000 data a second from serial; afaik even 100Hz is stretching it. also, the ADC can't do 1000Hz, so you're double-screwed ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have tried, the serial communication at 38400bd is enough to transmit an int at 1kHz. You can use 115200bds; your speed of 500000bds is not supported, even if it usually works.

The ADC will have no problem with 1000Hz. The Arduino command `analogRead` works at 10kHz; and if you would access register of atmel MCU directly, you could speed up analogRead to 100kHz.

Your code is slowed down with `drawnow`. You dont need to refresh at 1kHz; if you refresh at 10Hz, it will be real time for your eye.

In arduino sketch you should put a `delay(1)` (1ms), so you know the serial buffer wont get full.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I have things working now.

Answer (score 0):

also , to speedup the transfer speed, sending the data as binary will help a lot the `Serial.println(tempreading);` you used sends data as string. meaning it will send 6 characters each time. (5 characters + the CR). sending as binary will need only 2 bytes.
; a 3X speed increment already.
To send data as binary in arduino , use

```
serial.write(data_to_send>>8);        //send most significant byte
serial.write( data_to_send && f);     //send least significant byte
```